# callback onanimation Complete SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller

I have used an example to create an animation using a logo in SwiftUI. My main issue is that I would like to trigger a call to another view once the animation is completed, but I can't find one.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    var screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    
    @State var isLoggedin = false;
    @State var animate = false;
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack {
                Color("light_blue")
                Image("logo_splash")
                    .resizable()
                    .renderingMode(.original )
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: animate ? .fill :  .fit)
                    .frame(width: animate ? nil : 85, height: animate ? nil : 85)
                    .scaleEffect(animate ? 3 : 1)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                animateSplash()
            })
        }
    }
    
    func animateSplash() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4){
            withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.8)) {
                animate.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any idea How to call a function when the animation is completed ?

Thanks

Comment: You can add simply add delay for calling next thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/68396073/14733292 or more https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/withanimation-completion-callback/

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017784/12299030?